# Ошибка при клике на ListView, почему?

Tags: java, android

Есть:

```
ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> list4adapt = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Boolean> al_checked = new ArrayList<>();
```

В onCreate:

```
lv = findViewById(R.id.lv_base);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list4adapt);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            cur_pos = position;
            log("1");
            SparseBooleanArray chosen = ((ListView) parent).getCheckedItemPositions();
            log(" " + String.valueOf(chosen.size()));
            al_checked.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < chosen.size(); i++) al_checked.add(chosen.get(i));
        }
    });
```

log:1 проходит, а дальше рушится.
Сообщение:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.util.SparseBooleanArray.get(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: `getCheckedItemPositions()` возвращает `null`, если `ListView` задан режим `CHOICE_MODE_NONE` (устанавливается по умолчанию если не задано иное).

Answer (score 0):

Ваш `SparseBooleanArray` не возвращает ничего, он пуст. Попробуйте пределать так:

```
SparseBooleanArray chosen = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
if (chosen != null) {
log(" " + String.valueOf(chosen.size()));
al_checked.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < chosen.size(); i++) al_checked.add(chosen.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Да, но он не может быть пуст. ListView заполнен записями, это я наблюдаю на экране. В этом и проблема, почему он говорит что пустой.

Comment: Если бы там был `null`, то оно б упало на `chosen.size()`, не?

Comment: @kaaa, попробуйте сделать ребилд - потому что похоже на глюк - если там `null` - он реально должен был на  `chosen.size()` выстрелить.

Comment: я сделал и clean, и rebuild и перезагрузил комп, но глюк остался. Падает на log(" " + String.valueOf(chosen.size())), но на экране в lv список загружен. Мистика блин.

Comment: А, ну если на `size()`, тогда всё правильно - там `null`. Вы в тэге `ListView` атрибуту `android:choiceMode` задавали значение или в коде вызывали `listView.setChoiceMode(...)`? Если нет, то `getCheckedItemPositions()` всегда будет возвращать `null`.

Comment: Да, дело оказалось в вызове choiceMode, его не было! Благодарю.